# Hide JS error without custom error handler

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have one line of code that is throwing an error that I don't care about. I need to hide it from the console. I don't want to use a custom error handler and return false, because I want to see all other errors.

I've tried a try / catch, but the error still shows up in the console:

```
try{
    //the erroneous line of code
}catch(err){ }
```

I've also tried fiddling window.onerror right before the erroneous line, and fiddling it back right after, and the error still shows up in this case as well:

```
window.onerror = function(){ return false; }
//erroneous line of code
window.onerror = function(){ return true; }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the error? What's the code look like? What (demonstrated) have you tried?

Comment: could you post your code ? normally try/catch to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try catch is the one to use

```
b=a; // gives an error in the console
try {
  a = x; // does NOT give an error in the console
}
catch(e) {
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='ERROR: '+e.message;
}
```

I only get

a is not defined

in the console in my [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mplungjan/CL6WN/)

I do not get the SECOND error in the console. Not even after commenting out the first error just in case it possibly blocked further processing.